# How to add (Download on The App Store) Button in NopCommerce?

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

I'm trying to add (Download on The App Store) buttons (for both the app store and google play) in my nopcommerce website footer.

Any idea on how I can get it done?

Like This One

[image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @Div Nothing much. I'm looking for a plugin I can use, but couldn't find anything yet. Do you know if there is a plugin I can use or do I have to create buttons manually? If you have any tips or guidance I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any plugin is available for your requirement. But I can give you a reference to modify your code.

Go to: Presentation > Nop.Web > Views > Shared > Components > Footer > Default.cshtml

After the div `<div class="footer-block follow-us">` add your code:

```
<div class="footer-block information">
    <div class="social">
        <div class="title">
            <strong>Download it from</strong>
        </div>
        <img src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en_badge_web_generic.png" width="140" height="auto" />
    </div>            
</div>
```

It will display as below, also you can add for app store.

[image]

Perhaps, you can create a separate partial view and use here; that'd be the best practice instead displayed here.

Also, I'm not good in css, so didn't make much effort.